# Modelica array equation

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

In the Modelica 3.3 rev 1 language specification on page 99, there is the following parameter declaration.

```
parameter Real A[:,:] = [1];
```

What does `[1]` mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator [] is the concatenation operator. See page 15 and page 123: 10.4.2.1 Array Concatenation along First and Second Dimensions.
Basically you get as a result:

```
parameter Real A[1,1] = 1;
```